# Can't Adjust the camera position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't change the camera position in my game, the camera back to it's original position, I think its something wrong with my code, but i have no idea what is causing it.
Here's my Camera code:

```
private GameObject player;
    public float xMin;
    public float xMax;
    public float yMin;
    public float yMax;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("player");


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        float x = Mathf.Clamp(player.transform.position.x, xMin, xMax);
        float y = Mathf.Clamp(player.transform.position.y, yMin, yMax);
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, gameObject.transform.position.z);

    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Are the values maybe not what you expect? Can you do some Debug logs on the player position values and the clamp values?

Comment: Also, minor improvement suggestion... instead of finding the player object in Start, it's more performant to have a public Transform variable for a target which you can then drag your player into through the inspector to make it the target. Then you can maybe added some smooth following if that's an effect you want by using a [Vector3.SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) function.

Comment: @Tim Hunter thanks i will change the camera to transform, what is strange is the fact that the code looks ok.I will try to put the debug logs to see if something wrong is happening.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Hunter thanks i will change the camera to transform, what is strange is the fact that the code looks ok.I will try to put the debug logs to see if something wrong is happening.